# Loop through JSON and create prefab in Unity3D

Tags: c#, parsing, json, unity3d

I am creating an app in Unity3D and it is my first time coding in C#.
I use the following code to parse a JSON file hosted on my server and use the information to render prefabs within my scene:

```
    // Parses the json Object
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

AssetData assetData = parser.ParseString(mJsonAssetInfo.text);
mAssetData = assetData;

// Updates state variables
mIsLoadingAssetData = false;

for(var i = 0; i < assetData.Assets.Count; i++){
    GameObject newAsset = null;

    if(((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetType == "Text"){

        newAsset = (GameObject)Instantiate(asset, new Vector3(15*i, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        newAsset.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = ((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetContent;
        newAsset.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90, -180, 0);

        string[] rgba = Regex.Split(((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetBgcolor, ", ");
        float red = float.Parse(rgba[0]);
        float green = float.Parse(rgba[1]);
        float blue = float.Parse(rgba[2]);
        float alpha = float.Parse(rgba[3]);

        var child =  newAsset.renderer.transform.transform.Find("background");
        child.renderer.material.color = new Color(red/255, green/255, blue/255, alpha);

        float posXtag;
        posXtag = (((((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetLeft * 100f / 1024f)  + (((Assets)bookData.Assets[i]).AssetWidth * 100f / 1024f) / 2f))-50f;

        float posYtag;
        posYtag = -1*((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetTop * 50f / 512f - ((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetHeight * 50f / 512f / 2f +25f;

        newAsset.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(posXtag,0,posYtag);
        child.renderer.transform.localScale = new Vector3(((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetWidth/102.4f,0.2f,((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetHeight/102.4f);

    } else if (((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetType == "Image"){

        newAsset = (GameObject)Instantiate(iasset, new Vector3(15*i, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        newAsset.transform.parent = AugmentationObject.transform;
        Color color = newAsset.renderer.material.color;
        color.a = 0f;
        newAsset.renderer.material.color = color;
        string url = ((Assets)bookData.Assets[i]).AssetContent;
        StartCoroutine(DownloadImage(url, newAsset, ((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetFilename, "IMAGE"));

        newBrick.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);

        float posXtag;
        posXtag = (((((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetLeft * 100f / 1024f)  + (((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetWidth * 100f / 1024f) / 2f))-50f;

        float posYtag;
        posYtag = -1*((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetTop * 50f / 512f - ((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetHeight * 50f / 512f / 2f +25f;

        newAsset.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(posXtag,0,posYtag);
        newAsset.transform.localScale = new Vector3(((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetWidth/102.4f,0.2f,((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetHeight/102.4f);


    } else if (((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetType == "Video"){

        newAsset = (GameObject)Instantiate(video, new Vector3(15*i, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        newAsset.GetComponent<Playback>().m_path = ((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetContent;

        string url = ((Assets)newAssetData.Assets[i]).AssetThumbnail;
        StartCoroutine(DownloadImage(url, newAsset, ((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetFilename, "VIDEO"));


        newAsset.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, -180, 0);

        float posXtag;
        posXtag = (((((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetLeft * 100f / 1024f)  + (((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetWidth * 100f / 1024f) / 2f))-50f;

        float posYtag;
        posYtag = -1*((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetTop * 50f / 512f - ((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetHeight * 50f / 512f / 2f +25f;

        newAsset.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(posXtag,0,posYtag);
        newAsset.transform.localScale = new Vector3(((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetWidth/102.4f,0.2f,((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetHeight/102.4f);

    }

    newAsset.transform.tag = "Asset";


    // IF ASSET IS SET TO FADEIN DO THAT HERE:
    if(((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetFadein == "true"){
        iTween.FadeTo(newBrick, 1f, 1);
    } else {
        Color color = newAsset.renderer.material.color;
        color.a = 1f;
        newAsset.renderer.material.color = color;
    }
    // EOF ASSET FADEIN

    if(((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetAction != ""){
        newAsset.AddComponent("TouchListener");
        newAsset.GetComponent<TouchListener>().actionUrl = ((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetAction;
    }

}
```

My JSON file can contain information of 3 "asset" types (text, image or video), each asset type renders a different prefab (`Text` = asset, `Image` = iasset, `Video` = video).
I then set the different parameters for the prefab:

- Hieght
- Width
- position x-axis
- position y-axis
- background color (text only)
- texture (image and video)
- fadein animation (if set)
- touch action (if set)

My code works fine, but as it is my first time coding in C# I am sure there is a cleaner way of getting the job done.
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

I would split the asset loading into 3 different classes: `TextAsssetLoader`, `ImageAssetLoader`, and `VideoAssetLoader`.  This will allow you to separate the loading of each type.  Additionally, I would create an interface so you can eliminate the `if` statement in your current code.

```
public interface IAssetLoader
{
    GameObject Create(AssetData assetData, int index);
}
```

Then each class would be:

```
public class TextAssetLoader : IAssetLoader
{
    public GameObject Create(AssetData assetData, int index)
    {
        var newAsset = (GameObject)Instantiate(asset, new Vector3(15*index, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        newAsset.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = assetData.AssetContent;
        newAsset.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90, -180, 0);

        string[] rgba = Regex.Split(assetData.AssetBgcolor, ", ");
        float red = float.Parse(rgba[0]);
        float green = float.Parse(rgba[1]);
        float blue = float.Parse(rgba[2]);
        float alpha = float.Parse(rgba[3]);

        var child =  newAsset.renderer.transform.transform.Find("background");
        child.renderer.material.color = new Color(red/255, green/255, blue/255, alpha);

        float posXtag;
        posXtag = (((((Assets)assetData.Assets[i]).AssetLeft * 100f / 1024f)  + assetData.AssetWidth * 100f / 1024f) / 2f))-50f;

        float posYtag;
        posYtag = -1*assetData.AssetTop * 50f / 512f - (assetData.AssetHeight * 50f / 512f / 2f +25f;

        newAsset.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(posXtag,0,posYtag);
        child.renderer.transform.localScale = new Vector3(assetData.AssetWidth/102.4f,0.2f,assetData.AssetHeight/102.4f);
    }
}

// Next two clases are pretty much the same.
```

Your main loader then looks like:

```
public class AssetLoader
{
     private static readonly IDictionary<string IAssetLoader> Loaders = new Dictionary<string, IAssetLoader>
                   {
                       { "Text", new TextAssetLoader() },
                       { "Image", new ImageAssetLoader() },
                       { "Video", new VideoAssetLoader() },
                   };

     public void LoadAssets()
     {

          for(var i = 0; i < assetData.Assets.Count; i++)
          {
              var asset = assetData.Assets[i];

              GameObject gameObject = Loaders[asset..AssetType].Create(asset, i);

              // Rest of the code to deal with gameObject
          }

     }
}
```

On top of this change, I would suggest getting rid of all the casts in your code; `((Assets)assetData.Assets[i])` gets a little confusing.  If you have to cast it do it once as in my code, a better alternative is to have an `AssetData` class, and have the `Asset`s and `IEnumerable<AssetData>`. This way you don't have to ever cast it in your code; it is done on deserialization.

Standard C# guidelines suggest having opening and closing braces on separate lines:

```
if (something)
{
}
```

Other than making it easier to read, I don't see too much else that needs attention.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response @Jeff, I am going to integrate it and test and will post back